# Merge ms-office and openoffice into office

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

[openoffice](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openoffice) and [ms-office](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-office) both contain only a single question, and are rather addressing the documents to work with. I'd suggest to merge them into [office](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office) (x9) and optionally make them a synonym to the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disagree. They're completely different products and should not be conflated.

And, besides, I have re-tagged all of the [office](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office) questions to [ms-office](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-office), [openoffice](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openoffice), or some other tag(s) if neither of those was appropriate.